# How to implement a server and client call to Apache CXF, Spring and Ws-AtomicTransaction service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, transactions, cxf

I have rather simple question to ask, although I haven't found an answer. I have two Apache CXF contract-first services implementations with Spring integration. I will refer to them as **Service Apache One**, and **Service Apache Two**.

My bussiness logic requires to create a client application (**Client One**) that interacts with these two servers (the application should be developed also using Spring framework). Both services should support transactions. **Service Apache One** have an operation called *OperationOne*, and **Service Apache Two** has an operation called *OperationTwo*.

The **Client** performs an operation called *OperationClient*, that orchestrates a bussiness logic that should call to *OperationOne* and after, call to *OperationTwo*. *OperationClient* should be atomic, so, if the call to *OperationTwo* fails, then *OperationOne* should rollback. I think this is achieved by using WS-AtomicTransaction.

Here comes the question. How can I implement this call? What should I put on my **Service Apache One** and **Service Apache Two** and what should I put on my **Client** so the transaction includes both web services calls, in a way that if the second call fails, it will rollback the first call also?

Comment: Long story short, Apache CXF (and many other web service based framework) won't offer you a ready to go feature for this. You may try to implement an agnostic solution with WS-AtomicTrasaction or change to a Eventual Consistency approach.

Comment: Ok, so how can I implement a solution with WS-AtomicTransaction an Apache CXF?

Comment: E.g.: Deploy your Apache CXF WS in GlassFish and follow this https://metro.java.net/guide/ch18.html

Comment: I am using Spring to publish my Apache CXF service. In that case what should I do?